# Mongoose update functions cannot add new fields until I add the field in schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I recently faced a very strange problem with mongoose. I was trying to add a new field in all documents of my collection, so I used below code:

```
myModel.updateMany({},{$set:{new_field: true}},(err, result)=>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
 });
```

The above code printed this:

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

I tried using the `async/await` version, `updateOne`, `update` with `multi` set to `true`, but nothing worked. Then I added `new_field` in the schema, and the above code worked.

But that shouldn't be the approach. Whenever we want to add a new field, we should be able to add it without specifying it in schema. I don't understand what is going wrong here.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing `$set` {$set : {new_field: true}} -> {new_field: true}  or add brackets around {$set:...} -> [{$set:...}] ?